# if condition and for loop in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need to check whether a file is created and locked or not, using a batch file,
if the file is locked the program should wait and check periodically whether the file is released from lock, and when it gets unlocked the program should exit.

I am very new to writing batch files (started today)

This is what I have tried:

```
@echo off
:loop
if (2<nul (>>test.txt echo off))(
    goto END
)
else (goto MESSAGE)
:MESSAGE
echo trying to access file
goto loop
:END
pause
```

Comment: If you've just started, and you have some flexibility, I'd suggest using [tag:PowerShell], instead.

Comment: What are the results when you run this?  Are you getting an error?  If so, edit your question and add the error. If not, what are the results?

Comment: I assume you mean a Windows batch file, and not DOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close :) But you cannot use IF to directly test whether a command succeeded or not. Use the `||` conditional operator instead.

Assuming you mean Windows, and not DOS:

```
@echo off
:loop
2>nul (
  (call ) >>test.txt
) || (
  echo Trying to access file
  timeout /nobreak 1 >nul
  goto loop
)
```

`(call )` is simply a very efficient way to perform a no-op that always returns success.

The TIMEOUT introduces a 1 second delay to prevent the loop from hogging CPU resources.

See [How to check in command-line if a given file or directory is locked (used by any process)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10518151/1012053) for more info on how the above works.

Comment: hey, thanx a lot for the reply, but the 'timeout' was not recognized by the system so i modified that line by adding ping 1.1.1.1 -n 5 -w 3000 > nul now it works fine. Got it from here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-5-seconds-in-windowss-command-prompt-or-dos)