# Use Rmdir with thisworkbook.path

Tags: vba, excel, rmdir

In Excel 2016 VBA I used:

```
kill ThisWorkbook.path & "\reports" & "\*.csv"
```

to remove all the .csv files in the directory - which worked fine.

My problem is that i want use:

```
path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\reports\"

RmDir path
```

to delete the folder. I cant seem to figure out what im doing wrong.

Comment: Are there no other files in the directory?

Comment: Are you trying to delete the folder that contains the currently open workbook? Doesn't sound viable

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: error 75 I am guessing or 76

Comment: Save the ActiveWorkbook somewhere else first.

Comment: @steenbergh the directory is empty and the error message is "error75"

Comment: @QHarr the error message is 75. the directory is completely empty

Comment: @braX the activeworkbook is saved already

Comment: Are there any hidden files contained inside? Seems to work for me with an empty folder.

Comment: Saved where? in the folder you are trying to delete?

Comment: @qharr Nope. i even checked with the command line - just to make sure

Comment: @brax so the location of the active workbook is:  C:\Users\Justin Field\Desktop\Test
the folder i want to delete is 
C:\Users\Justin Field\Desktop\Test\reports

Comment: Is the folder somehow locked? And can you use fso deletefolder instead?

Comment: @qharr how would i find that out?

Comment: That's what I am googling at present! Meantime did you try fso.DeleteFolder path

Comment: I just did a test and put a test folder in the folder i want to delete: C:\Users\Justin Field\Desktop\Test\reports\deleteme\. Then i used the code: RmDir "C:\Users\Justin Field\Desktop\Test\reports\deleteme\" and that works. I just cant seem to delete the reports folder . arrrrggg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518151/how-to-check-in-command-line-if-a-given-file-or-directory-is-locked-used-by-any  Also did you try without the end "\" - shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @qharr i have never used that before. Ill look into it meow

Comment: add reference to ms scripting runtime then      Dim fso As FileSystemObject:

Set fso = New FileSystemObject :

: fso.DeleteFolder path    without end "\"

Comment: what command did you use to test no hidden files?

Comment: @qharr - you are right. I went to delete the folder conventionally and it said, "the action cannot be completed because the file is open in another program". Now i need to find out what program is doing this. freaking nuts

Comment: See the link I shared